# How to really block autoplay media in Firefox 79?

Tags: firefox, autoplay

Here are settings about autoplay in my Firefox 79 :

[image]

Despite these settings, some videos are autoplayed. On this page for example [HERE](https://itsfoss.com/linux-system-monitoring-tools/), when I scroll down to the bottom of the page, the hidden video is then moved and displayed to the right and when my mouse hovers over it, without clicking, the video starts on its own. So, how to really stop the autoplay in Firefox 79? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually, though, most sites get through this by JAVA script(s). To _really_ shut it off you have to disable the scripting, which could lead to not showing pages correctly, some links may not work and menues not displaying or acting right. Even if you shut it all off in Firefox, not matter which version, it will probably always play do to the scripting and even just through direct links.

Comment: Extensions such as uBlock Origin allow selective disabling of large media, i.e., videos; JavaScript, etc. on a *per site* basis.